# Best way for App backgrounds resources paths

Tags: android

I have multi Hi-res backgrounds, which need to be scaled down to fit the lower screens, as suggested in Stack Overflow, I've put them in `drawable` folder. I don't know if its correct or not, so i tried to test.

I had the `OutOfMemory` exception, therefore i had to move them to `drawable-nodpi`, it worked well without any exception, but i don't know if this is the correct way to use it in Android.

Any suggestions for this? some said i need to make for each-screen background, like `xxhdpi`, `xhdpi`, but i thought making a background in the highest screen, and scale it down better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've put them in drawable folder. I don't know if its correct or not, so i tried to test.

If you put a drawable in the `drawable` folder, Android will use that drawable for all screen sizes, scaling the drawable to reflect the device's density (e.g. an `xhdpi` device will blow up the image 2x).

> I had the `OutOfMemory` exception, therefore i had to move them to `drawable-nodpi`, it worked well without any exception, but i don't know if this is the correct way to use it in Android.

Drawables in a `-nodpi` folder will not be scaled at all. If you desire scaling, that is not what you want.

> but i thought making a background in the highest screen, and scale it down better?

If you only include the highest resolution image in your APK then Android must load the entire image into memory when you use it. If you have a 500x500 image that you are displaying on a 100x100 screen, Android will need to load the entire 500x500 image into memory.

Devices with small screens tend to have less memory, so this is likely to lead to an `OutOfMemoryException`.

From a design perspective, you also don't have any control over what the scaled down image looks like. Depending on your use case, this may be fine.

> Any suggestions for this

The correct way to do this would be to pre-scale your drawables and place them in the appropriate drawable folders. The 1x asset goes in `drawable-mdpi`, an asset scaled to 1.5x goes in `drawable-hdpi`, etc. Then Android will load only the correctly sized asset for the device's screen size.

Comment: Added to Tanis answer, check the [Android asset generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) to generate different scaled versions of the image. Having separate png's will increase the apk size if the image is Hi-Res. If apk size matters for you then consider using [Vector Drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, and for @blizzard your comment really, really helped me out, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

There are some point to be taken care of.
1. You should optimize the image as much as you can so that in low end device 
   while loading the image OutOfMemory error is not there.
2. Take a high resolution of image and based on the device your application will 
   support place that image in xxhdpi or xxxhdpi resource folder.
3. Android automatically scale down maintaining the aspect ration on the image 
   while loading.